# Can we merge word-choice and some related tags?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

I'm seeing what looks like a bit of a mess with a number of related and possibly overlapping tags:

- [selecion-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selecion-de-palabras)
- [term-choice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term-choice)
- [terminology](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)
- [term-request](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term-request)
- [nuances](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuances)
- [connotations](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connotations)
- [meanings-definitions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meanings-definitions)
- [word-usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage)
- [phrase](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase)
- [expression](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression)
- [distincion](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distincion)
- [figure-of-speech](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figure-of-speech)

Can some of these tags be merged or collapsed into some distinct categories?  I see some obvious distinctions between some of these, but I don't think there are as many distinct concepts as there are tags in the above list.  How can this be improved?

Answer (score 2):

Some quick thoughts without looking too deeply before my netbook battery dies:

- [terminology](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) - keep separate. this tag is used in many SE sites and is about terminology related directly to the field the site covers. So Spanish grammatical and linguistics terms for starters, maybe other kinds of terminology specific to Spanish too?
- [term-request](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term-request) - this is about looking for a term when you know the meaning, not about choosing one of several terms
- [connotations](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connotations) see previous
- [meanings-definitions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meanings-definitions) - this is about getting the accurate meaning or definition of a term, not about choosing between multiiple terms, or looking for a term to match a concept
- [word-usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage) - this is a poor tag in my opinion. [usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) is probably better
- [phrase](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase) - this is the worst tag on the site in my opinion - it's a useless meta tag that pointlessly separates topics about phrases from topic about single words, and leaves topics that could involve a single word vs a multi word term without an appropriate tag. plus there's not a spanish word to differentiate the english senses of "phrase" and "sentence".
- [expression](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression) - this is another bad tag - is it to do with idioms?

The following items are completed:

- [selecion-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selecion-de-palabras) - merge with [term-choice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term-choice) *merged*
- [term-choice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term-choice) - see previous *merged*
- [distincion](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distincion) - without digging deeper this looks like another tag for choosing or distinguishing between two terms or possibly two grammatical constructions. *burninated*
- [nuances](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuances) - merge with [connotations](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connotations) though I believe english.SE decided both were bad tags *burninated*
- [figure-of-speech](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figure-of-speech) - not clearly distinguished from the "expression" tag above. *no longer exists*

Comment: I like this thoughts. "phrase" usually covers questions about a phrase in Spanish or to be translated to Spanish, like "buenos días" or "Can I help you?", that is, translations or meanings that are not single words. I would remove this. However, I would let "expression" live, for questions like "qué aproveche", set phrases. "Idioms" are a subset of "expression", I don't know if we should merge them or not.

Comment: Idioms have the key property that it is not possible to understand them just because you understand the parts that make them up. This key property makes it very useful to have on its own separate tag from plain vanilla phrases. People are interested in idioms and would favourite such a tag, etc.

Comment: EL&U has a *connotation* tag which is different from ours. And they decided that [*nuance* is a bad tag](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/1367/9983), and their reasoning seemed to apply to every one of our 9 *nuance* questions; so I removed the *nuance* tag from our questions. I also removed the *conntations* from questions that were really *word-choice* (*selecion-de-palabras*) questions.

Comment: About [tag:expression], there are many cases that might fit well, like in "What is the expression used for greeting in a birthday"? 
What I don't know is if tagging these questions as "expression" is useful.

Comment: Yes *expression* can mean pretty much anything from *phrase* or *term* to *idiom* or *proverb*, sometimes even *word*. Such vague terms don't really help anybody as a tag.

Comment: @hippietrail After having cleaned some *phrase* tags, I see now it was not useful at all, there are a lot of many different things under this tag.